# Write input lines in reverse order

Tags: java

> Write a Java program that takes all the lines input to standard input and writes them to standard output in reverse order. That is, each line is output in the correct order, but the ordering of the lines is reversed.

I wrote this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the line");
    String a=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the line");
    String b=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(b+" "+a);
}
```

Is this efficient?

Comment: You should test it.

Comment: not very good as this only allows two lines to be entered. Consider using an ArrayList

Comment: I'd prefer a [`Stack<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Generally I would agree, but for a user of this level adding the use of a ArrayList to his `tool-belt` would be of more benefit, no?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Perhaps, but I'd still prefer the collection best for the problem at hand. A [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) might be a good choice too.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by one of the comments a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) would be a good data structure to achieve this:

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deque deque = new LinkedList<>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your lines (Enter exit to continue):");

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
      String line = sc.next();
      if(line.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {
        break;
      }
      deque.add(line);
    }

    System.out.println("\n=====Reversed Lines=====\n");        

    Iterator reverse = deque.descendingIterator();
    while (reverse.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(reverse.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FFmX/1)

Comment: But it is not printing the output.

Comment: type exit then enter